# Only error logs are printed in server.log in wildfly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server, wildfly

I have created a `war` file with `spring-boot` project (version 2.7.0) for deplying in `wildfly` application server. I have a sample rest API

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloApi {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        System.err.println("TEST LOG");
        return "Hello from Spring Boot";
    }
}
```

The issue is that `System.out.println` output is not written in the `server.log` whereas `System.err.println` is in fact printed in the `server.log` file.

This is sample code. In my actual application, I am using `slf4j` for logging. I am facing the same issue there : `info` method is not working but `error` method is. Seems like some sort of configuration issue. My `pom.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
    <deploy.wildfly.host>MY_HOST</deploy.wildfly.host>
    <deploy.wildfly.port>MY_PORT</deploy.wildfly.port>
    <deploy.wildfly.username>USERNAME</deploy.wildfly.username>
    <deploy.wildfly.password>PASSWORD</deploy.wildfly.password>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                <hostname>${deploy.wildfly.host}</hostname>
                <port>${deploy.wildfly.port}</port>
                <username>${deploy.wildfly.username}</username>
                <password>${deploy.wildfly.password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can someone please help me regarding this? I am new to spring. In my wildfly setup there are other wars deployed (not using spring) but they are working fine.

Thanks

Comment: Does your deployment contain a logging configuration file?

Comment: No. Earlier I was using the embedded Tomcat as my server. It was working fine, all error and info are logged into the console. Now I am creating a `war` file and deplying it to `WildFly`. Everything is working except that only error messages are printed in `server.log`. Both with `System.out/err` and `slf4j` info/error.

Comment: Do you see other info messages?

Comment: There are other wars deployed from which I can see all the logs. But not from my sample war.

Comment: It should work by default. You might want to look to see if you've got a configuration file in your WAR or if you're including log libraries in your WAR.

Answer (score 0):

The sl4j config is in a separate file not in your pom.xml.

Check this link: https://www.swtestacademy.com/how-to-configure-simple-logger-slf4j-log-levels/

You should actually use the logger factory to log and not system.out or system.err:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
logger.info("Hello World");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why the standard output is not redirected to the `server.log` file then, only the standard output?

Comment: I am already using the logger factory and I have added the properties file in my project. Still it's not working.

Comment: Where does the question reference log4j?  How do you know that is the underlying logger for slf4j?

Comment: I am using `slf4j` for logging.

Comment: The issue is still present even when using LoggerFactory/log4j. If I recreate the database tables it magically starts working again, though. But then after a few restarts it's back to just ERROR only, that and System.out.println()'s.

Comment: Update: now not even dropping & recreating the tables is fixing it.

Comment: Update again: it turns out having the logging level set to DEBUG was ironically causing it to only print ERROR to server.log?